# Can I access scene nodes' properties in the view controller?

Tags: swift, scenekit

I want to manipulate a nodes property when a user taps on the screen.

For example: 
I have in my scene a node called box. How do I unhide the box when the user taps the screen?

Comment: The Apple template code shows how to manipulate a node in response to a tap. What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I can't find that code, if you should just show me where in the documentation there is an explanation of how to make a node respond to a tap that would be much appreciated

Comment: In Xcode, create a new Project (command-shift-N). Choose iOS Application, Game. Choose SceneKit from the Game Technology popup that appears. Study GameViewController.swift.